# Use System Reflection To Find Lists Of All Types From Class Properties

Tags: c#, database, reflection

I'm pretty new to programming, and I'm teaching myself. Any and all help is appreciated, but please be understanding -- I don't really know what I'm doing that well. Also, this is the first question I've ever posted on SO (I sure have read a lot of other people's, so thanks for all that), so if I need to modify anything about how I'm asking, please let me know. Thanks!

I'm working on creating a Xamarin application in Visual Studio.I created a mock database to serve mock information to my application. The MockDatabase file is a POCO with static lists to hold the information. There are 11 lists for the models that I created that will eventually map to the SQLite database file I'm planning to use in the future. Here's a snapshot of the file:

```
public class MockDatabase : IDataStore
{
    public static List<tblAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    public static List<tblCrew> Crews { get; set; }
    public static List<tblCustomer> Customers { get; set; }
    public static List<tblEmployee> Employees { get; set; }
    //etc...

    public MockDatabase(bool createMockData = false)
    {
        if (createMockData)
        {
            Addresses = Addresses ?? MockData.MockAddresses();
            Crews = Crews ?? MockData.MockCrews();
            Customers = Customers ?? MockData.MockCustomers();
            Employees = Employees ?? MockData.MockEmployee();
            //etc...
        }
    }
```

[The static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) does what I want, that even if I initialize multiple instances of the class, each of them points to the same static instance of the list. So, the problem that I'm having with using static lists is that it works too well. When I run my unit tests in a consecutive run, the tests are getting the data that a previous test set, which meant I had to rewrite the tests to account for this. I solved the problem by calling `MockDatabase.Addresses = new List<tblAddress>();` in my test initialization, but I really wanted to use something that would work more broadly, and not need to be specialized for each test class that I'm creating.

Here's what I had written:

```
[TestClass]
public class AddressRepositoryTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        MockDatabase.Addresses = new List<tblAddress>();
    }
```

But what I was trying to accomplish was to have the MockDatabase use some reflection to find all lists within itself and reset their value. I tried a number of variations on the following code, but I couldn't find anything that worked.

```
[TestClass]
public class AddressRepositoryTests
{
    [TestInitialize]
    public virtual void SetUp()
    {
        (new MockDatabase()).ClearDatabase();
    }
```

```
public void ClearDatabase()
{
    var properties = typeof(MockDatabase).GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(IList<BaseModel>))
        {
            property.SetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I put a break point inside the `if` statement and tried a number of different code variations, and nothing ever returned `true`.

Thanks for any help!

**Edit**

I don't know how to use the generic `List<T>` in the middle of a method. Sticking it into the line produces the compiler error "The type or namespace T could not be found..."

```
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(IList<T>)) //Will not compile
```

I also tried comparing against `List<object>`, but that fails too.

```
if (property.PropertyType == typeof(IList<object>)) //Fails
```

Comment: have you tried List<T>.Clear() ?

Comment: Can you explain where I would put that code? I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: The accepted answer is fine but know that storing the values in the static members means you'll need them until the class is unloaded. To clear them garbage collect them yourself, you can use [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I feel like the answer I accepted does indeed match the question I asked, but your suggestion seems to point towards a 'best practice' that I don't know about or know how to implement. Could you point me in the right direction? Documentation, other SO posts related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try changing ClearDatabase function as below:

```
public void ClearDatabase()
{
    var properties = typeof(MockDatabase).GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType.Name == typeof(List<>).Name || property.PropertyType.Name == typeof(IList<>).Name)
        {
            property.SetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I didn't know that `List<>` could be used with no type argument! In stepping through the code, the first comparison `List` evaluated true, and the second comparison `IList` evaluated false.